# avoiding conflicts with php file_put_contents

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fclose, file-put-contents

I am logging visitor custom search queries to a text file as follows:

```
define('SEARCH_LOG', 'log.txt');
file_put_contents(SEARCH_LOG, "\n" . $search, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH | FILE_APPEND);
```

Every 100 searches, I sort and collate the entries and email them to the site owner. Then I clear the file as follows:

```
file_put_contents(SEARCH_LOG, "", FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

I understand that `file_put_contents` is identical to calling `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, and `fclose()` successively.

1. Do I need to worry about collisions between users or is this somehow
   handled for me?
2. Do I need to write a conditional retry?
3. Should I use the `LOCK_EX` flag?

Comment: it could happen (though not seen it personally), either it will be inconsistent data, like one log line gets ignored whilst the other writes, or partial data etc, using LOCK_EX would cause one to fail one to succeed etc, I'm not aware of fpc implementing retry but you could do https://3v4l.org/ttaXh - though all these issues go away, with benefits, if you store the searches in the db

Comment: Thank you @LawrenceCherone! If you want to post your reply as an answer with the code from the link, I'll mark it answered.